# Blender Can't Find GPU

Tags: rendering, gpu

I have 2 *NVIDIA GTX 1080 Ti*s with updated drivers and CUDA installed.

I’m currently trying to render my scene in Blender 2.81 (though this happens on other versions of Blender as well) on Ubuntu 18.04.

When I go to Preferences, then System, and finally Cycles Render Devices, the 2 GPUs are listed under the CUDA tab.

However, after rendering a couple of times, it seems that the GPUs stop working all of a sudden, as if I go to check Cycles Render Devices afterwards, it now says

No compatible GPUs found for path tracing. Cycles will render on the CPU

If I list the devices in Blender’s Python Console using:

```
bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.devices
```

it seems that the 2 GPUs are visible to Blender:

> CyclesDeviceSettings(“GeForce GTX 1080 Ti”)
>
> CyclesDeviceSettings(“GeForce GTX 1080 Ti”)

I also notice when I try to start Blender up, I get this error:

> CUDA cuInit: Unknown error

It seems that the only way to solve this error is to restart my computer, after which the GPU rendering option is available, until this issue repeats itself.

Any ideas on why this might happen?